# Problem Getting Verification Code in Google Drive API Using PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm a student developing a web app which uses PHP server. I need to implement Google Drive API in my application. I followed the quickstart guide provided here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php.
Upon executing `quickstart.php` in the shell it displays a link and asks for the verification code. Using that link I signed in with my Google account,
but the problem is after signing in, it redirects me to XAMPP dashboard where I can't find any code.

Where can I find the code?

Comment: Which credentials did you choose? Moreover, are you getting the names of the files?

Comment: i have used credentials provided at the time of creating the project which was in JSON format,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the url of the redirected page there will you get two variables first code and other scope copy the value of code and paste it and you will done